# Sample size recaluculation

Tags: size, sample, estimation

can one recalculate the sample size for an interim analysis after a sample size is determined already for the final analysis of a clinical trial. And this number of recruitement has been achieved?

ways to recalculate the sample size, whether this adhere to GCP, I feel that this is not possible to do with the current stand of the recruitement